# How to open next viewcontroller after choosing image from gallery (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, ios8

I am trying to open next viewController after choosing photo from gallery. I can get image from gallery, but after that I dont know how to open controller next to it.   !.[This is photo of that storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaeL9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside your `UIImageView` using Interface Builder or in code (as you want), I prefer the first. The you can put an `@IBAction` and handle the tap inside your `UIImageView`, Don't forget to set the `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` in Interface Builder or in code.

To present the next view controller you can do it in code like below or just using Interface Builder using a segue through the `UITapGestureRecognizer` you set before (it's up to you).

To present the view controller manually like in the following code you need to set the **Storyboard ID** for you view controller like in the following picture (in the **Identity Inspector panel**):

[image]

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Set the storyboard name by default is Main
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)

    // Instantiate the ViewController with the name you set before like in the image
    let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB") as! UIViewController

    // present the nextViewController
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I hope this help you.